# Multiples Project Persist Spring Data

Tags: spring, jpa, xsd, spring-data

I'm Having a Weird problem with Spring Data.

I Have 2 different projects, witch one have your schema on postgres.

on the first project i can do the CRUD in any entity and everything work's fine.

And in the second project, i have dependency of the first project, i can do the CRUD in anything of the second project and list anything of the first project. But i can't persist anything of the first project

I Realize that if i throw this line

```
<import resource="classpath*:applicationContext.xml" />
```

in the end of my Application context of the second application, i CAN persist anything of the first project on the second project, BUT i CAN'T persist anymore the things of the second project.

And if i let this line in the begginning of the application-context.xml of the second aplication it will persist normal the model of the second projet.

here it is the complete XML Application-context of the second project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Carregar os dados applicationOrcamento.properties na memória -->

<!-- <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:applicationOrcamento.properties" 
    ignore-unresolvable="true"/> -->

<import resource="classpath*:applicationContext.xml" /> <!-- this line that i'm having problem Application Context of the first project if this line is here, i can persist anything of the second project, if i put on the end will persist any thing of the first project, but nothing of the second project... -->

<!-- Activates scanning of @Autowired -->
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan
    base-package="br.com.secondProject.package.repository" />

<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.secondProject.package.services" />

<!-- <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.firstProject.package.repository" 
    /> -->

<!-- <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.firstProject.package.services" 
    /> -->

<jpa:repositories base-package="br.com.secondProject.package.repository"
    entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactoryOrcamento" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator" />

<!-- Database -->
<bean id="datasourceOrcamento"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB?searchpath=second_project" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="123456" />
</bean>

<!-- Entity Manager -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactoryOrcamento"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasourceOrcamento" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="second-project-pu" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <!-- <property name="generateDdl" value="true" /> -->
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="br.com.secondProject.package.model" />
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Alterar para JTA quando for para produção! -->
<!-- <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:/prject-ds" id="datasource" resource-ref="true"/> -->

<!-- Transaction Manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryOrcamento" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

`

Ther Persistence.xml of the second application is also importing the classes of the first project, th real problem is persist an entity of the first project on the second project

i have already tried to put on my controller the

```
@ContextHierarchy({
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContextOrcamento.xml"}), //second Project xml
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:applicationContext.xml" })// first project xml
```

})

but doens't work...

i just need to persist an entity of the first project inside the second project

Comment: It seems that there is too much code samples in your question. The question is not obvious. Please consider reducing code and emphasizing the problem.

Comment: i've tried man... but it's such an stupid problem that i can't even explain better then i tried hahaha. If i change one line, one thing work and the other don't

Comment: I suppose that in the applicationContext.xml you import there are another datasource, entityManager, transactionManager etc. So maybe there is some collision. Try to use only the ones from the imported applicationContext.xml.

Comment: Hey i solve here, it was a naming problem in my Application context of the second project.